# replace infinity loop without new thread

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

```
    for(;;)
    {
        ...// CPU usage and etc...
        printf("Server is up: %.0f sec\n",diff_time); //seconds of running for example
        sleep(1);
    }
...//other server code
```

I'm writing a server program. I need to output information every 1 second about CPU usage, etc...
Code above works, but server code after loop will be never completed.
Anyone have any idea how to replace this infinity loop with something that will do every second?
Unfortunately,without thread and child process. Any other ideas.

Comment: Without another thread/process, I don't think it is possible. Not if you are particular about 1 second.

Comment: That completely depends on what your server does.  (hint: there are probably threads already)

Comment: Maybe you can use the shell to do the server-monitoring for you, using `watch` in conjunction with starting your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm interesting

if you are in linux do the below

man -a timer_create

should be able to provide a solution otherwise
[Click Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the server is accepting connections, you can use [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)/[`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)/[`epoll_wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait) to wait for a readable event.

You can choose to use a timed wait for the event, in which you would do your timed handling after a timeout. Or, you can use a interval timer (see [`setitmer()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer)). For the latter, your alarm signal handler can wake up your polling wait by writing to a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), where the read end of it is also being waited on for a readable event.

Comment: I suggest not using `select` (google for `C10K problem` ....), `poll` and `epoll` are better...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I agree `epoll` is best to use on `Linux`. I mention the others because the literature on single threaded concurrent servers still largely use them in their examples.

Answer (score 0):

No threads? Not even [POSIX threads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html)? Well, the only other way I can think of would be this:

```
/*
* Pseudocode.
* The purpose is to model what the code might look like.
*/

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Initialization */
time_t t0 = time(0);

while (serverRunning) {
    /* Server code */

    if (difftime(time(0), t0) >= 60.0) {
        t0 = time(0);

        /* Print information here */
        printf("Info");
        printf("More Info");
        printf("Even More Info");
    }
}
```

**But this is assuming your backbone is in C to begin with.** Could you provide more information?